# Flutter 120fps issue

Tags: android, flutter

scenario:
have an application in flutter with a hard-coded list of 20 cards after a release build of this on my 120 fps devices it still feels like 60 fps how to fix it while the native android counterpart has a smooth render at 120 fps.

have tries the above scenario will the scrolling based widget both builder-based and normal ones.

Is it a flaw in flutter that it doesn't render at 120 fps.

Answer (score 5):

On Android phones with 120hz display by default is chosen the wrong display mode (e.g. 60hz instead 120hz). This can easily be corrected, then performance on phones like Oneplus 8T or Galaxy S20+ is great.

1. Import [`flutter_displaymode` library](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_displaymode):

```yaml
flutter_displaymode: ^0.3.0-nullsafety.0
```

2. Add this to your root widget (stateful):

```dart
class _YourAppState extends State<YourApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    setOptimalDisplayMode();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> setOptimalDisplayMode() async {
    final List<DisplayMode> supported = await FlutterDisplayMode.supported;
    final DisplayMode active = await FlutterDisplayMode.active;

    final List<DisplayMode> sameResolution = supported.where(
            (DisplayMode m) => m.width == active.width
                && m.height == active.height).toList()..sort(
            (DisplayMode a, DisplayMode b) =>
                b.refreshRate.compareTo(a.refreshRate));

    final DisplayMode mostOptimalMode = sameResolution.isNotEmpty
        ? sameResolution.first
        : active;

    /// This setting is per session.
    /// Please ensure this was placed with `initState` of your root widget.
    await FlutterDisplayMode.setPreferredMode(mostOptimalMode);
  }
}
```

Note, that right now there are no 120hz iPhones, so there is no need to execute them.

Comment: There now is iphone 13 pro with 120hz refresh rate. I wonder if someone will test this case :)

Comment: I don’t have one, sorry.

Comment: This package is not working on iphone13 pro

Answer (score -2):

You must profile your performance metrics. check out this https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/ui-performance

Comment: Tried that. Even tried simply rendering a long text still the same.

Comment: some android devices needs sets the screen refresh rate, check out these comment https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35162#issuecomment-564770280

Comment: and this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35162#issuecomment-604761374

Answer (score -13):

> Please try this, you can use media query for sizing your widget.
>
> ```
> MediaQuery.of(context).size
> ```

Comment: what does it have to do with 120fps?

Comment: you can adjust your card size

Comment: consider using ListView(children: List<Widget> ) instead of ListView.separated(itemBuilder: )

Comment: @RohitSoni, you know you can delete your answer if you realize its not very useful. (you'll get back your points too)